# Why safari in mac and safari in iPhone look different?

Tags: google-chrome, web, safari

I am styling page in css. Using chrome + chrome dev tools for development. But tester has reported different visuals in iPhone and safari(chrome) outcome looks the way i intended it to. Why iPhone safari looks completely different?

Any explanations?

Comment: It would help if you provide some screenshots and code.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone Safari and Safari(chrome) are two different applciation with different source code. Their release version and CSS, Javascript support differ . 
However both try to follow the standard and latest css, javascript coding guidelines and syntax/semantics, but may be not exactly both release the same support at same time.
infact iPad safari and Mac book Safari are different many times.
Chrome on Desktop machine and Chrome on Android devices differ due to same above reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, colleague advised to use

```
web-kit-appearance: none;
```

And that worked.